# Algorithms that depend on expected time and "regular" time complexities

Tags: time-complexity

Assume that I have designed an algorithm A, which runs two sub-methods: M1 and M2.

M1 has a O($n$) expected time complexity.

M2 has a O($n^2$) time complexity.

Clearly A uses O($n + n^2$) = O($n^2$) time. Since $n^2$ > $n$, in terms of time complexity, should A be described as having an **expected** time complexity of O($n^2$), or can the expected term be dropped as the $n$ term was dropped?

Comment: What does “expected O(n)” mean?

Comment: @gnasher729 - In this case, I use expected time like any algorithmic article would. It means that the algorithm is randomized in some form, and has been analysed as one. I could be more specific; assume that M1 creates a dictionary containing n elements. Using perfect hashing (FKS - "Storing a sparse table with $O(1)$ worst case
access time"), this can be done in $O(n)$ expected time. (As perfect hashing has random elements due to choice of hash function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that $M_1$ is a randomized algorithm and that the expectation is taken over the random bits.

If you just say that $A$ has time complexity $O(n^2)$, the default assumption is that your are talking about *worst-case* time.
Then it would be incorrect to say that $A$ runs in time $O(n^2)$ since (without further assumptions on $M_1$), it could be the case that $M_1$ takes time $\omega(n^2)$ on some bad executions.

However, since $M_2$ runs in time $O(n^2)$ anyway, you can claim that $A$ runs in time $O(n^2)$ *with high probability*. Indeed, by Markov's inequality, $M_1$ takes $O(n^2)$ time with probability at least $1-\frac{1}{n}$. If you perform $c$ parallel and independent executions of $M_1$ and stop as soon as one halts, then the running time will be $O(cn^2)$ with probability at least $1-\frac{1}{n^c}$. For $c=O(1)$ this allows you to pick any arbitrary large (but constant) exponent in the probability lower bound while keeping the running time in $O(n^2)$.